# My Ubuntu 22.04 not waking up from after locking device(window key + L)

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lock-screen

My Ubuntu 22.04 not waking up from after locking device(window key + L)

My device is Asus vivobook 16x Ryzen 7 5000 series